# Remove hidden points under the minimum

Tags: highcharts

I want to have a chart that displays values only over the 'min' value for the yAxis ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Vangi/fjea9byp/)):

```
$('#container').highcharts({
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
    },

    yAxis: {
        min: 100
    },

    series: [{
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
    }]

});
```

But actually Highcharts shows shadow and tooltip of the points which are under the minimum:
[image]

How can I configure Highcharts to ignore those points which are outside the chart plot?

Comment: The best way is to remove the points that you don't want to see from your data first...

Comment: Lines from points should be printed or not (I mean line which cross xAxis) ?

Comment: Yes Sebastian Bochan, this is the point. The lines should show there are some points out of range but the points should not be active/visible (no tooltip, no shadow). Any idea how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

use formatter function in toolTip:

```
    tooltip: { 
        formatter: function() {
     if (this.y  < this.series.yAxis.min) return false; else return  this.series.name + ': ' + this.y;
     }}
```

See [fiddle with your example](http://jsfiddle.net/Nishith/fjea9byp/1/)

Comment: Hi Nishith Chaturvedi, thanks for the answer but I still see shadow of the outside points and I don't like the hard coded values like this.y <100.

Comment: if you don't want hard-coded values , you can use this.y < this.series.yAxis.min